# Problem to get working Three.js without expo (using react-native-unimodules)

Tags: javascript, react-native, three.js

I am trying to display any 3d view, however all I got is blank screen, no errors.
React-native-unimodules is set up properly but ExpoGL does not working for me. Tried few other examples found in web but none of them did not work..
I am using React-native version: 0.61.4

I would be gratefull for help with my code, or any working example of three.js in react-native (in bare project, without expo). Thanks in advance

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

import { GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import { THREE } from 'expo-three';
import ExpoTHREE from 'expo-three';
 

export default class App extends React.Component {

    private renderer: any;
    private scene: any;
    private camera: any;
    private geometry : any;
    private material : any;
    private obj : any;
    private line : any;
    private edges : any;;

  constructor(props : any) {
    super(props);
    this._onGLContextCreate = this._onGLContextCreate.bind(this);
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
  }

  _onGLContextCreate = async gl  => {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      gl.drawingBufferWidth / gl.drawingBufferHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    this.renderer = new ExpoTHREE.Renderer({ gl });
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0f00 });
    this.obj = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
    this.edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(this.geometry);
    this.line = new THREE.LineSegments(
      this.edges,
      new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
    );

    this.scene.add(this.line);
    this.scene.add(this.obj);
    this.animate();
  };

  animate = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    this.obj.rotation.x += 0.01;
    this.obj.rotation.y += 0.01;
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GLView
          style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
          onContextCreate={this._onGLContextCreate}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for it. I'm stuck with the same problem. Once I import expo-three my app goes to a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

> I guess the camera parameters did the trick.

```
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, gl.drawingBufferWidth / gl.drawingBufferHeight, 1, 5000 );
    this.camera.position.z = 1500;
```

> Additionally I scaled the mesh items so that it is visibly well

```
this.obj.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
this.line.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
```

> One last thing, adding camera to the scene is not required. So I removed it.

```
// this.scene.add(this.camera);
```

So finally the code looks like

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import * as THREE from "three";
import ExpoTHREE from 'expo-three';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._onGLContextCreate = this._onGLContextCreate.bind(this);
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
  }

  _onGLContextCreate = async (gl)  => {
        
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, gl.drawingBufferWidth / gl.drawingBufferHeight, 1, 5000 );
    this.camera.position.z = 1500;

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
    this.scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x000000, 1500, 4000 );

    this.renderer = new ExpoTHREE.Renderer({ gl });

    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0f00 });
    this.obj = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
    this.edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(this.geometry);
    this.line = new THREE.LineSegments(
      this.edges,
      new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
    );
    this.obj.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
    this.line.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );

    this.scene.add(this.line);
    this.scene.add(this.obj);
    this.animate();
  };

  animate = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    this.obj.rotation.x += 0.01;
    this.obj.rotation.y += 0.01;
    this.renderer.clear();
    this.camera.lookAt( this.scene.position );
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GLView
          style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
          onContextCreate={this._onGLContextCreate}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```